# Append a Query in text format To the end of an IQueryable result

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I want to select data from a SQL Server database with Entity Framework e.g.

```
_dbset.Where(x=>x.bookType == 2 && Level == 2)
```

Then I want to show the selected data in kendo grid but the "where" that I give to the query is a SQL type of string and it's not invariable.

If I want to select like the below example it would be very slow

```
string stringWhereQuery = "bookType  == 2 AND Level in (1,2,4,6,9)"
_db.Database.SqlQuery<T>("select * from book where " + stringWhereQuery);
```

How can I give the `stringWhereQuery` to the end of the Ex1 and return it in `IEnumerable<T>`?

Would you recommend a better way to do this?

**Kendo Grid EX:**

```
public ActionResult REFDARMANREQRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var temp = new ComBigDataService<WMISREFDARMANREQMSTView>().GetAll(x=>x.bookType == 2 && Level == 2);
    var data = temp.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The first example works pretty fast but the second example, which contains the `stringWhereQuery` works very slow because there is too much data in the database, around 5 million rows.

Comment: What is the possible syntax of your where string? Is it a valid SQL Where clause? Why do you think the `SqlQuery` would be slower than EF query - the EF query is just translated to a SQL Query and sent - performance should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert level string to array and use below query.

```
int[] levels = new int[]{1,2,4,6,9};
_dbset.Where(x=>x.bookType == 2 && levels.Contains(x.Level));
```

Comment: my where clause is in type of string.
depends on the situation it can be changed.
there can be no level at all